# My flag summary has stopped working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, flags, flag-history

For some reason, my flagging summary isn't showing me what's happened with any of the flags I posted since the end of October. In other words, none of the flags that I've posed in November are showing up in my flag summary. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's what I am seeing:
[image]

Comment: What *is* it showing you? A redacted screenshot would help.

Comment: Ok, give me a minute

Comment: It's only been a week since the end of October. It's possible that your flags just haven't been resolved yet? I'm not sure how large the flag backlog is.

Comment: Even if the flag queue was backlogged, in the past all my flags have always showed up. Only, those that haven't been dealt with yet are shown as pending.

Comment: You are saying that you flagged posts on November, but they are not shown in your flag history. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yep. I've flagged stuff in November, but it's not showing up in my flag queue.

Comment: Oh. Interesting. Come to think of it, that's happened to me, too, but I dismissed it as "maybe I misclicked and didn't actually submit the flag". So... yeah, repro here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: I flagged an answer, and the flag summary reports it, even if it is still waiting for review.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have over 3K reputation, if you are flagging anything as `duplicate, off topic, not constructive, not a real question, or too localized`, your flags are being converted to close votes.  These will not show up on your flagging record.

Spam/Offensive, not a real answer (and its variants), and "Other" flags will still be recorded.

Comment: Oooooooo. I see now. Didn't realize that. Thanks for explaining that to me.